# Google Sheets - pull multiple lines of data from Workbook1 based on A1 in Workbook2

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, vlookup

Ok.  So I've been all over this looking for an answer to my problem. I found so much helpful info, but none of it quite solves my problem. So I am here to ask the experts myself.

I work for a photography company and I am creating a dashboard in Google Sheets that will pull information from our Contacts, Workflow, Schedule, etc. I have been able to work all of it out except the workflow. This has me caught up because we schedule the same school multiple times a season and I need workflow items to appear for both photoshoots (*see ABC School 1 in example images*).

Because of privacy issues, I can't link the actual dashboard I'm working on. But I have screenshots of what I'm working with.

I've tried vlookup, filter, index, and query. There is a very good chance the solution is in one of those functions, I just can't figure it out.

On the dashboard, I need the rows next to "photoshoots 1/2/3" to pull from the "Workflow", based on the school name I have in 'A1' of the Dashboard.

In the workflow, it will find multiple rows with that school name (I need to pull data from all lines of 'ABC School 1'), so each occurrence of the school name would appear as one of the lines labeled "photoshoot 1/2/3".

I hope I have provided enough information!

[image: Dashboard Example]

[image: Workflow Example]

Comment: What determines 1,2,3?  Sorted by date but only return 3 most recent?

Comment: *"Because of privacy issues, I can't link the actual dashboard I'm working on"* Create some sample data and share it anonymously using the [Blank Sheet Maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform)